# The number of integer points in a circle of radius $\sqrt{n}$ converges to $n\pi$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that for the number $\mu(n)$ of integer pairs $(x,y)$ with $x^2 + y^2 < n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ holds $\mu(n) / n \longrightarrow \pi$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

(This is exercise 7.6 from "Algebraic Number Theory" by Stewart & Tall)

I recognise that this is related to the Gauss circle problem. By the formula for the area of a circle it is clear that we can estimate $\mu(n) \approx n \pi$; note that the radius of the described circle is $\sqrt{n}$.

However, I fail to see how to formalise this argument, i.e. how to show that

$$\mu(n) \longrightarrow n\pi.$$

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: $\mu(n)/n\to\pi$ is not at all the same  as $\mu(n)\to n\pi$.

Comment: **Hint:** Write $\mu(n)$ in terms of a sum over pairs of integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2\lt n$, i.e. $$\mu(n) = \sum_{x^2\lt n}{\ \sum_{x^2+y^2\lt n}{1}}$$

Comment: Intuitively, the area near the boundary is small compared to the area of the circle, so the number of points near the boundary grows as $\sqrt n$ while the number clearly inside grows as $n$.  For large $n$ the boundary doesn't matter.